# How to disable dragging but still show tooltip on fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I have my code like this :

```
eventMouseover: function(calEvent, jsEvent)
{
     xOffset = 0;
     yOffset = 0;
     tiptext = "";
     var view = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView');
     if (view.name == 'month')
     {
        if (tiptext)
        {
           tiptext = "<strong>" + calEvent.title + "</strong>" + "<br>" + tiptext;
           $("body").append("<p id='tooltip'>" + tiptext + "</p>");
           $("#tooltip")
              .css("z-index", 91000)
              .css("position", "absolute")
              .css("top", ($(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight() + yOffset) + "px")
              .css("left", ($(this).offset().left + xOffset) + "px")
              .fadeIn(400);
        }
     }
  },
  eventMouseout: function(calEvent, jsEvent)
  {
     $("#tooltip").remove();
  },
```

and on my eventrender:

```
if(calEvent.title == "Holiday")
{
   element.draggable = false;
}
```

And I have a tooltip to describe the holiday event,
the tooltip works fine, however if I set draggable to false, the tooltip wont show anymore.
Can I still show my tooltip eventhough draggable set to false?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please create a [jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/) so we can assist you further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are manually disabling the draggability of your holiday event. Instead use the [`editable`](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_ui/editable/) event option. Either define it when you define your events like:

```js
events: [{
    start: moment(),
    title: "Holiday",
    editable: true,
},],
```

Or add it inside the [`eventDataTransform`](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/eventDataTransform/) callback:

```
eventDataTransform: function(eventData){
    if(eventData.title === "Holiday")
        eventData.editable = false;
    return eventData;
},
```

This option should disable dragging (and resizing) without removing the tooltip functionality.

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/slicedtoad/9rxrx4fb/2/)